# NUnit test for QueueClient in Microsoft ServiceBus

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, azureservicebus

I am creating `mocking` for `QueueClient`. I have `GetQueueClient` in `ServiceBus class`. I am using below code for it.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Moq;    

[TestFixture]
    public sealed class FetchingTest
    {
        private Mock<IServiceBus> mockIServiceBus;
        private Mock<QueueClient> queueClient1;

        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            this.mockIServiceBus = new Mock<IServiceBus>();
            this.queueClient1 = new Mock<QueueClient>();
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestPagingUsesCorrectOffsets()
        {
            this.mockIServiceBus.Setup(p => p.GetQueueClient(Constants.FetcherQueueName)).Returns(queueClient1.Object); // Getting error here
        }
    }
```

**Service Bus Class:**

```
using Microsoft.ServiceBus;
public class ServiceBus : IServiceBus
    {
private static readonly string ServiceBusConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ConnectionStringNames.ServiceBus];

public QueueClient GetQueueClient(string queueName)
        {
            return QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ServiceBusConnectionString, queueName);
        }
}
```

It is throwing an error

> Parent does not have a default constructor. The default constructor
>   must be explicitly defined.
>   System.NotSupportedException

Can someone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: you should use `IQueueClient` abstraction instead.

Comment: @Nkosi I tried to use it but I am unable to import the required library.

Comment: If unable to access it then consider creating your own abstraction and implementation that wraps the actual client

Comment: Just checked and the interface is public. Why can't you access it

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the [QueueClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient?view=azure-dotnet)

Ensure that you are depending on abstractions instead of implementations to avoid problematic implementation concerns.

```
public interface IServiceBus {
    IQueueClient GetQueueClient(string queueName);
}

public class ServiceBus : IServiceBus {
    private static readonly string ServiceBusConnectionString =
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ConnectionStringNames.ServiceBus];

    public IQueueClient GetQueueClient(string queueName) {
        return QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ServiceBusConnectionString, queueName);
    }
}
```

That way abstraction can be mock as needed when testing

```
[TestFixture]
public sealed class FetchingTest
{
    private Mock<IServiceBus> mockIServiceBus;
    private Mock<IQueueClient> queueClient1;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Setup() {
        this.mockIServiceBus = new Mock<IServiceBus>();
        this.queueClient1 = new Mock<IQueueClient>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestPagingUsesCorrectOffsets() {
        //Arrange
        this.mockIServiceBus
            .Setup(_ => _.GetQueueClient(Constants.FetcherQueueName))
            .Returns(queueClient1.Object);

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: We are using `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging` and so, it conflicts with `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`.